# Django: call class function in form_valid

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a class based view. I want to update a field in a model whenever it is saved. This field isn't set by the user; it is a field that says the form data has been changed and needs to be reapproved. One way I am thinking about going about this is in the `def form_valid` to query the model and set the field to the value I need. The query that I'm running is also in a function defined on this class. Can I run this function in `def form_valid` instead of realling it? All my attempts are proving fruitless.

```
class CUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    def get_object(self):
        qs = C.objects.filter(
                    c_id = self.kwargs.get('c_id')
                )

        if qs.count() == 1:
            if self.request.user == qs.first().a.user or self.request.user == qs.first().inhouselandmanager.user:
                pass
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied 
            return qs.first()
        raise Http404

    def form_valid(self, form): 
        if self.object.status != 'initiated':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('c:detail', kwargs={'c_id': str(self.object.c_id) }))
        qs = super().get_object()
        qs.update(approved=False)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `super().get_object()` which will call `get_objects` of parent class, use `self.get_object()`:

```
def form_valid(self, form): 
    if self.object.status != 'initiated':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('c:detail', kwargs={'c_id': str(self.object.c_id) }))
    qs = self.get_object()
    qs.approved=False
    qs.save() 

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Also since `qs` is single object you cannot use `update()` method with it. Just use normal `save()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get the object from there, get it from `form.instance`. And `update` is a method on querysets, not model instances; just assign the attribute directly.

```
def form_valid(self, form): 
    if self.object.status != 'initiated':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('c:detail', kwargs={'c_id': str(self.object.c_id) }))
    form.instance.approved = False
    return super().form_valid(form)
```